# How to make a vector with variables that have different template parameters?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, vector, function-pointers

I'm making a program were all the buttons need to be in a vector so I can easily call the render function for all of them with a for loop. I created a shortened down version of my problem. So the code below has the class called Button. When I create a Button variable I have to send the class containing the function I want to be called and the function pointer in the template. When I call the buttons Pressed function it will call the function I sent. When I call the buttons Render function it will render. I then have two different classes with functions that should be called when there corresponding button is pressed. I haven't used templates before so i'm not sure how I would put the buttons into a vector if the buttons have different template parameters so i cant write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
    buttons[i].Render();
}
```

instead of:

```
    button1.Render();
    button2.Render();
    button3.Render();
    but...
```

Right so here is the code:

```
template<class CWF> //CWF = Class with Function
class Button {
public:
    typedef void(CWF::*eventMethod)();

    Button(CWF& cwf_, eventMethod method_) : method(method_), cwf(cwf_) {};
    ~Button() {}

    void Pressed() {
    (cwf.*(method))();
    }

    void Render() {};

private:
    eventMethod method;
    CWF& cwf;
};

Class1 class1;
Class2 class2;
Button<Class1> button1 = Button<Class1>(class1,&Class1::MyButtonWasPressed);
Button<Class2> button2 = Button<Class2>(class2, &Class2::MyButtonWasPressed);

int main() {

    // loop here
    button1.Render();
    button2.Render();
    //      

    //exiting herer
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It makes little sense having a template parameter just for the sake of calling a function in a pretty much unrelated class. Just get rid of the template parameter so all buttons are the same class and hence work ok with vector, and have Button take an std::function<void()> as callback for the click event and be done with it. Also don't use global variables unless you really have to.

Comment: Do you know of a good resource to learn about std::function<>? I've never seen it before.

Comment: The internet, basically. Like http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/264061-c11-fun-with-functions/

Comment: I have fixed my problem. Than you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option in your example is to just remove the template altogether, and instead pass a `std::function` with your callback.

However, if your needs are complicated enough that that is not feasible, you would need to implement some form of type erasure. The most intuitive way would be to make your template class derive from some interface that provides the functions you need:

```
class AbstractButton {
public:
    virtual void Pressed() = 0;
    virtual void Render() const = 0;
};

template <typename CWF>
class Button : AbstractButton {
public:
    // ...
    void Pressed() override { /* ... */ }
    void Render() const override { /* ... */ }
};
```

To use:

```
// store in vector
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractButton>> buttons;
buttons.push_back(std::unique_ptr<AbstractButton>(new Button<Class1>(/* ... */)));
    // (or std::make_unique if you have C++14)

// use:
buttons[i]->Render();
```

Comment: The button constructor now contains std::function<void()> as a parameter which is saved to a variable. When the buttons pressed function is called it will call this function.

Comment: Thank you very much